# Changing title's color - Classic thesis template

Tags: color, templates, thesis, classicthesis, default

Default color of the title is red in classic thesis template.
I tried to search the word red in the file Titlepage.tex, ClassicThesis.tex and classicthesis-config.tex, but there is not.

How can I change the title's color?

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis?lang=en.

---

EDIT: the default command in the Titlepage.tex is:

```
\begingroup
\color{CTtitle}\spacedallcaps{\myTitle} \\ \bigskip
\endgroup
```

If I modify it with:

```
\begingroup
\color{CTtitle}{blue}\spacedallcaps{\myTitle} \\ \bigskip
\endgroup
```

the color remains the same with the word blue at the beginning of the title:

[image]

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: No, you don’t write `\color{CTtitle}{blue}`. Instead, you write `\color{blue}\spacedallcaps{\myTitle} \\ \bigskip`. My solution intentionally changes the meaning of `CTtitle` so the replacement of color is done in a consistent way. Making changes such as yours *may* glances over other components.

Comment: @RuixiZhang thank you for your excellent solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can’t find `red` is because the color is not exactly `red`. The color is `Maroon`, which is stored in `CTtitle` and is used in the article/book title and the part titles.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\colorlet{CTtitle}{blue}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\end{document}
```

[image: title color]

Comment: Hello @RuixiZhang, see the edit please.